# How to iterate through random or specific values in a range? in a non sequential way, in Python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, nonsequential

The way Python iterates through a range in a for loop is given the range from (0 to n) it will do the operations first for 0, then for 1, 2... until it finishes in n, completing the for loop. Am I correct?
I have a working code that needs to be optimized for speed, it looks something like this:

```
Phi = np.arange(0.00005, 0.000101, 0.000001)
Strip_depth = 0.001
for angle in Phi:
    Neutral_axis_depth = np.arange(150, 160, 0.0001)
    for xn in Neutral_axis_depth:
        Sn = int(xn / Strip_depth) 
        x = [0]  # strip center coordinates
        for i in range(0, Sn - 1):
            x.append(x[i] + Strip_depth)
...
# and the a lot of calculations that will eventually result on C and T
...
        comparison_parameter = 0.1
        dif = T - C
        if comparison_parameter > dif > -comparison_parameter:
            # here I need to print the corresponding values of Phi, Xn , C, T and dif in a table
            # but that's another question...
```

My problem is that I need a high precision on the result and for that I have to modify either the **"strip_depth"**, or the **"Neutral_axis_depth"** np.range *step*, which will cause more operations and will take more time.
I thought that instead of performing the iterations in Xn in a sequential way I could save time by picking a random value in the range and continuing depending on the value, for example:

if **dif** is *negative* I can neglect the values of the range from that point forward
if **dif** is *positive* I can neglect the values of the range before that point

and repeat this while **dif > comparison_parameter**. This way the operation is not done Sn times, only a few. Another option would be to decide the values for the iteration, like 1/3rd of the range, 2/3rd of the range, and then 1/3rd of the "remaining range" or something like that.
In a way I'm defining a new range with these steps. Either way I don't know how to do this...thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly follow, but it seems like `range()` isn't the best choice for this use case. If you want to adjust the chosen value as needed, then use `while` + custom variable adjusted manually:

```
i = 0 # initiate the custom variable 
while i < Sn - 1: # instead of range()

    # under normal circumstances increase `i` in each loop by 1
    i += 1

    # if specific conditions are met, increase the value as needed
    if dif < 0:
        i += 50
```